# iReport plugin for Netbeans7.2 can't "replace with current document" in JasperServer repository

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, netbeans-7, netbeans-plugins

I am trying to change `main.jrxml` in *JasperReports Server* repositiory using *iReport plugin* for *NetBeans* today, but it is not working.

*NetBeans* is throwing the exception:

> Error; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXException: bad envelope tag: html

I've read answers and advice, but nothing has worked. However stand-alone *iReport 4.5.0* is working fine. Did anybody solve this problem?

The versions *JR Server* and *iReport Plugin* are the same (4.5.0)

I can't do anything (*i.e. rename/replace/insert*) with *JR Server* repository with *iReport plugin* but I can with *iReport* stand-alone.

Comment: It seems to me that it is a bug, you can see the [SAXException: Bad envelope tag: html](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/543991/saxexception-bad-envelope-tag-html) post. May be you should try to upgrade both applications to the 4.7.1 version...

Comment: Another related posts: [Bad envelope tag: html when trying to replace report or document with iReport 4.5.1](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/bad-envelope-tag-html-when-trying-replace-report-or-document-ireport-451) & [repository error](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/540163/repository-error). Did you try to contact with Jaspersoft support?

Comment: @AlexK Nothing is worked unfortunately.  But I noticed - this bug is from NetBeans 7.2 and above only. Previously version Netbeans(6.5.1 - 7.1) is working good.  Unfortunately it is not allowed to upgrade JasperServer from 4.5.0 to 4.7.1 for me  P.S. Sory for my English

Comment: I found bug.  It seems to me that error through conflict between __iReport__ plugin and __Java SE__ plugin. When I deactivated Java SE, error was disappeared

Comment: I think it will be better to post this solution as an answer